# Deleting Multiple Rows in a Matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

I'm working on writing a program that takes data from a CSV and turns it into a table to be exported to a PDF. The CSV I am working with has a bunch of empty rows so when I create my Matrix in Python, I have a bunch of empty rows. I want to delete all rows beginning with ''.  The code I wrote is:

```
i=0
x=rows-empty ##where empty has been defined and the number of rows I need to delete.
for i in range(x):
    if Matrix[i][0] == '':
        del Matrix[i]
    i+=1
```

The issue I'm having is if there are two consecutive empty rows only one is deleted. Any ideas on how to get rid of both lines?

I create and fill the Matrix using the following code:

```
##creates empty matrix
with open(filename) as csvfile:
serverinfo=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
rows=0

for row in serverinfo:    
    NumColumns = len(row)        
    rows += 1

Matrix=[[0 for x in xrange(9)] for x in xrange(rows)]  
csvfile.close()

##fills Matrix
with open(filename) as csvfile:
serverinfo=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
rows=0

for row in serverinfo:
    colnum = 0
    for col in row:
        Matrix[rows][colnum] = col
        if col==0:
            del col
        colnum += 1
    rows += 1
csvfile.close()
```

Comment: How are you reading/loading the CSV file? What is `Matrix` - are we dealing with `numpy` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting them after, just don't load them to start with. You can also short cut re-reading the file twice, as it appears you have a column limit of `9` set, so for each row, just pad it out with `0`'s to that size.... eg:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain, islice, repeat

COLS = 9 # or pre-scan file to get max columns
FILL_VALUE = 0 # or None, or blank for instance
with open(filename) as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin) # use appropriate delimiter/dialect settings
    non_blanks = (row for row in csvin if row[0]) # filter out rows with blank 1st col
    matrix = [list(islice(chain(row, repeat(FILL_VALUE)), COLS)) for row in non_blanks]
```

Depending what you're doing with the data, you may also wish to look at the `numpy` module and the available `loadtxt()` method.